# Polar to cartesian equation conversion

Tags: polar-coordinates

I have a polar equation defined as:

$r = ae^{θ \tan m}$

where, $a$ and $m$ are constants, $θ$ is the angle between the horizontal axis from the origin $(x_c,y_c)$ to the coordinate. $e$ refers to exponent.

The equation is illustrated below:

How can I express the above polar equation in Cartesian form? (i.e. I want to get the Cartesian equation that describes the line which passes through the coordinates as indicated by the broken red lines in the above illustration)

The motive behind this is to find the gradient of the broken red line given specified coordinates which lie along the broken red line.

Answer (score 2):

Your curve is a [logarithmic spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral) 
$r= ae^{b\theta} $ with $b=\tan m$.
You can express such curve in a parametric form as:
$$
x(t)=ae^{bt}\cos t
$$
$$
y(t)=ae^{bt}\sin t
$$

This is the simpler way to write out the cartesian coordinates.

Comment: could i check that theta in my case is the same as conventional definition?

Comment: From your graph it seems that $a>0$ and $\theta$ is taken clockwise. If this is the case you have to take $y(t)= -ae^{bt}\sin t$.

Comment: am i right to say that convention for the log spiral equation takes a <0 and theta anti clockwise?

Comment: The convention is $a>0$ ( $r$ have to be positive) and $\theta$ anti-clockwise.

Comment: when defined this way, does `r =sqrt(x^2+y^2)`?

Comment: Yes: $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and this is the reason of my answer.

Comment: oh i see, then,  θ remains as ` θ = arctan (y/x)` while with `y<0` right?

Comment: also, does `(xc,yc)` have to be at `(0,0)` (i.e. origin) for the basic convention of a logarithmic spiral equation?

Comment: Yes of course. Note that the sign of $y$ detrmine if the spiral is clockwise or anticlockwise.

Comment: if the origin is translated, would it be correct to say that `r = sqrt[ (x-xc)^2 + (y-yc)^2 ]` and `θ = arctan [(y-yc)/(x-xc)]` ?

Comment: You can see here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%281%2Be%5E%280.1+t%29sin+t%2C+1%2Be%5E%280.1t%29cos+t%29+for+t%3D-20+to+10 , and make your experiments :)